# formatting the binary representation of data in gdb

Tags: gdb

these days i use the examine memory feature of gdb a lot. however, i find the binary representation of data not very readable as all the bits are cramped together. i'd like to add some spacing to make it more readable, so for example instead of `01101100011011000110010101001000` i'll have `0110-1100-0110-1100-0110-0101-0100-1000` or something similar.

is this possible? the closest i got was `x/4bt s` which is close, but there are still two problems: the data is grouped in bytes (8 bits and not 4) which are layed out in reverse (so its `01001000 01100101 01101100 01101100`)

thanks

Comment: What is your version of GDB ? If 7.3 or later you can use python pretty printing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is something similar to pretty printers for GDB, they are most often use to print an STL / linked list etc. There might be some solution for your need that already exists so google a bit for pretty printers.

The below script is just an example of how you can write a custom command with python extensions, this will work of GDB version 7.3 and greater, however I tested it for version 7.5.

```
import gdb

class ppbin(gdb.Command):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ppbin, self).__init__("ppbin", gdb.COMMAND_USER)

    def invoke(self, arg, tty):
        print arg

        arg_list = gdb.string_to_argv(arg)

        if len(arg_list) < 2:
            print "usage: <address>, <byte-count>"
            return
        res = gdb.execute("x/%sxt %s" %(arg_list[1], arg_list[0]), False, True)
        res = res.split("\t")
        ii = 0
        for bv in res:
            if ii % 4:
                print "%s-%s-%s-%s-%s-%s-%s-%s" %(bv[0:4],   bv[4:8],
                                                  bv[8:12],  bv[12:16], \
                                                  bv[16:20], bv[20:24], \
                                                  bv[24:28],bv[28:32])
            ii += 1

ppbin()
```

Invoking the new ppbin command

```
(gdb) source pp-bin.py 
(gdb) ppbin 0x601040 10
0x601040 10
0000-0000-1010-1010-0011-0011-0101-0101
0000-0000-0000-0000-0000-0000-0000-0000
0000-0000-0000-0000-0000-0000-0000-0000
0000-0000-0000-0000-0000-0000-0000-0000
0000-0000-0000-0000-0000-0000-0000-0000
0000-0000-0000-0000-0000-0000-0000-0000
0000-0000-0000-0000-0000-0000-0000-0000
0000-0000-0000-0000-0000-0000-0000-0000
(gdb)
```

Above code is shared https://skamath@bitbucket.org/skamath/ppbin.git

P.S. - I usually find debugging memory in hex (x command) is easier than binary, so I will not use my solution.